# How to step frame back in DirectShow.NET?

Tags: c#, directshow, frame, directshow.net, seek

I suppose it should be done with `IMediaSeeking SetPositions`, but I don't know how define parameters inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no dedicated method to step back in DirectShow (as such existing for stepping forward). Yes you can use `IMediaSeeking::SetPositions`, however but note that it is not DirectShow itself who implement it, but actual underlying filters, so support for re-positioning depends on filters and implementation, and may be limited to, for example, stepping through key frames (splice points) only. DirectShow.NET is onyl a wrapper over DirectShow and it also does not add anything on top what DirectShow offers for stepping.

Comment: Ok, I know, but have you maybe some good examples to seek forward and backward?

Comment: You can seek forward with `IVideoFrameStep::Step`, this works pretty well. As for stepping backwards, the easy way is to seek to time position certain number of milliseconds prior to current. It is also perhaps possible to put a caching filter into pipeline, so that it holds frames and assists in stepping backward accurately, but it sounds like a complicated item just to be able to do such a  [supposedly] simple thing.

Comment: There are no examples for C# in Windows SDK, so the best place to look for samples is http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
IBasicVideo                 *pBasicVideo=NULL;//Interface to the Ibasic Video
HRESULT                     hr;
REFTIME                     pavgfrt=0;//Get the reftime variable
REFERENCE_TIME      pnowrt=0;//Get the reference time variable
pBasicVideo->get_AvgTimePerFrame(&pavgfrt);
pBasicVideo->get_AvgTimePerFrame(&pavgfrt);//Get the avg time per frame in seconds

pSeek->GetCurrentPosition(&pnowrt);//Get the current time in the unit of 100 nanoseconds
REFERENCE_TIME temp=pnowrt;//store it in a temp variable
REFERENCE_TIME temp1=(REFERENCE_TIME)(pavgfrt*10000000);//convert avg time into the format of current time
pnowrt=temp+temp1;//Add to framestep forward and subtract to framestep backward
pSeek->SetPositions(&pnowrt,AM_SEEKING_AbsolutePositioning, NULL,AM_SEEKING_NoPositioning);//Set the seeking position to the new time
pnowrt=0;//Reset the time variable
```

This works for me in C++.  Wrapping this code in C# may not be difficult for you. Hope this helps.